# how to mock a method that throws an exception

Tags: scala, playframework-2.6

The following method throws an `exception` if a `question` is not found

```
  def getQuestionFromQuestionID(questionKey: PracticeQuestionKeys) = {
    logger.trace(s"getting question with keys ${questionKey}")
    val practiceQuestionFuture: Future[Option[PracticeQuestion]] = findOne(questionKey)
    for (questionOption <- practiceQuestionFuture) yield {
      questionOption.fold(throw QuestionNotFoundException())(question => {
        logger.trace("got question " + question)
        question
      })
    }
  }
```

I call it like the following in a `controller`.

```
    def function1(){...
        val res = for{existingQuestion <- questionsRepository.getQuestionFromQuestionID(questionKey) 
res.recover{
case exception =>...
}...}
    ...}
```

I am writing a test for `function1` simulating that an exception is thrown. I wrote the following but I get `dead code` error when I compile the code.

```
when(answerTestEnv.mockPracticeQuestionsRepository.getQuestionFromQuestionID(ArgumentMatchers.any[PracticeQuestionKeys])).thenReturn(
    throw QuestionNotFoundException()
  )
```

Error

```
Error:(92, 9) dead code following this construct
        throw QuestionNotFoundException()
```

I changed the code to

```
when(answerTestEnv.mockPracticeQuestionsRepository.getQuestionFromQuestionID(ArgumentMatchers.any[PracticeQuestionKeys])).thenThrow(
    QuestionNotFoundException()
  )
```

But the test case fails with error

```
Checked exception is invalid for this method!
Invalid: utilities.QuestionNotFoundException: Question not found
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Checked exception is invalid for this method!
Invalid: utilities.QuestionNotFoundException: Question not found
```

How can I simulate the exception scenario?

Answer (score 0):

For methods with return value you can use `.thenThrow` (I's assuming you are using mockito, because scalamock uses different conventions)

```
when(
  answerTestEnv
    .mockPracticeQuestionsRepository
    .getQuestionFromQuestionID(ArgumentMatchers.any[PracticeQuestionKeys])
).thenThrow(new QuestionNotFoundException())
```

and if the method is of type `void` (`Unit`) you use `doThrow(ex).when(mock).call`:

```
doThrow(new QuestionNotFoundException())
  .when(answerTestEnv.mockPracticeQuestionsRepository)
  .getQuestionFromQuestionID(ArgumentMatchers.any[PracticeQuestionKeys])
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried `thenThrow` and was getting error `Checked exception is invalid for this method!`. I corrected it by adding `@throws(classOf[QuestionNotFoundException])` above `def getQuestionFromQuestionID(questionKey: PracticeQuestionKeys) = {`

Comment: but now the issue seem to be that the `exception` throws but it is not getting handled. I'll open a new question for this though.